# how do I read each element in the array and assign it to something

Tags: python

I'm currently working on making a syntax analyzer in python that reads an ada program as a txt file and i need to read each element in an array and assign it to print something.

This is the code I have for reading the file and putting it in the array

```
with open("resultForOne.txt", "r") as ins:
    array = []
    for line in ins:
        array.append(line)
```

this is what I'm getting when i print the array

```
['lexeme is function _____Token is keyword\n', 'lexeme is a _____Token is identifiers\n', 'lexeme is ( _____Token is symbol\n', 'lexeme is ) _____Token is symbol\n', 'lexeme is x _____Token is identifiers\n', 'lexeme is = _____Token is symbol\n', 'lexeme is 1 _____Token is const\n', 'lexeme is print _____Token is keyword\n', 'lexeme is ( _____Token is symbol\n', 'lexeme is x _____Token is identifiers\n', 'lexeme is ) _____Token is symbol\n', 'lexeme is end _____Token is keyword']
```

i want to read each lexeme and assign it to print some stuff

Comment: What is your expectations?

Comment: i expect to read each element and print a specific message for example for array[0] it'll print ```<program> -> function id() <block> end```

Comment: I think you really need to properly map your array input to the expected output (and add it to the question body, not here), this example you gave is still not really clear.

Comment: The fact that the program is intended to read Ada code does not make this an Ada-related question. The "ada" tag should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I think you are looking for readlines

```
with open("resultForOne.txt", "r") as ins:
    array_ = []
    for line in ins.readlines():
        array_.append(line.strip() )
```

If that is the case, then

```
with open("resultForOne.txt", "r") as ins:
    array_ = [i.strip() for i in ins.readlines()]
```

You can do your prints doing the reading process or after

```
for item in array_:
    print(f'[INFO] -> {item}')
```

If you want to do it during processing

```
with open("resultForOne.txt", "r") as ins:
     array_ = []
     for line in ins.readlines():
         print(f'[INFO] ->  appending {line.strip()}')
         array_.append(line.strip() )
```

Hope this helps